# Fail to run MySQL in Mac OSX 10.5.8

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, osx-leopard

my mac is a powerPC. and I have tried both 64 bit and 32 bit version of MySQL.

Both return me "bad CPU type in executable" when I try to do this /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

I followed all the steps as specified in the mysql official website.

- Well.. I have put my question in superuser.com  but that site just too few people .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL dropped support for PowerPC in version 5.1.40

The last version 5.1.40 can be found [here](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/mysql-5.1/mysql-5.1.40-osx10.5-powerpc-64bit.tar.gz)

Comment: still doesn't work. :(  at the end, when I run mysql-start, I got the same Bad CPU type error.

Comment: @murvinlai Check my revised post, I think I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to install mysql via **brew**

[Link](https://brew.sh/)